# What are the advantages / disadvantages of compiling a github library before including it in your project?

Tags: c++

What the the benefits of compiling a library prior to linking it to your project?

My understanding is that a non compiled version (if available) will result in a smaller overall size. Why would this not be the preferred way to include libraries then?

Comment: Static linking does indeed lead (generally) to a smaller overall program size, since you only ship the code in the library that gets used. It is however awful in other ways. (0) the whole application needs to be re-built and distributed when a bug in the library is fixed. (1) I'll give away the binary (.dll or .so) of a library I developed for personal use but like many am _far_ more reluctant to include the source unless you're throwing money at me.

Comment: How would you use a C++ library without compiling it?

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld Can't you include the library's source code in your project directory and include the library's header file? Even for C libraries, isn't the only additional step is to let the compiler know that it's a C library using `extern "C"` and then compile everything together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you exactly mean by "compiling library" prior to linking? You can compile it as static library and link it, in this case (assuming that LTO is used) result will be the same as compiling it as part of your project. You can compile it as shared library and link it. First case will result in smaller overall size when your project has only a single build artifact so you'll benefit from having only necessary parts of library code present in your build artifact. Second case will result is smaller overall size when your project has several build artifacts so you'll benefit from avoiding library code duplication in every build artifact.